# Installing Open MPI via MacPorts

Tags: macos, macports, openmpi

I want to use MPI in XCode.

[There](http://www.underworldproject.org/documentation/OpenMPIDownload.html) is a page when installation process of Open MPI is described. But it says I should have openmpi in `/usr/local/openmpi` but I haven't. Instead of this I have `/opt/local/include/openmpi` for headers and `/opt/local/lib/openmpi` for libs.

It also says that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is should include a folder with openmpi libs, but in that folder only `LA` and `SO` files are placed, neither `LD`, nor `DYLD`. All totally messed up in my head with those environment variables. Can somebody clarify this for me?

Answer (score 3):

`sudo port install openmpi` and **macports** will take care of everything.